# Generate thumbnail from url showing passthrough error (pdf-thumbnail)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
  async function generatePdfThumbnail(pdfUrl, taskId) {
  try {
        // Download the PDF file
        const response = await axios.get(pdfUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
        const pdfBuffer = Buffer.from(response.data);
    
        const fileId = uuid.v4();
        const pdfFilePath = "reciept/" + fileId + ".pdf";
        const thumbnailFilePath = "reciept/" + fileId + ".png";
        
        // Generate thumbnail
        const thumbnailBuffer = await pdfThumbnail(pdfBuffer, {
            resize: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200
            }
        });
        const data = await uploadToS3(thumbnailBuffer,taskId)
        // Return the thumbnail Buffer (can be uploaded to S3)
        return data;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error generating PDF thumbnail:', error.message);
    return null
  }
} 


async function uploadToS3(buffer, taskId) {
    try {
      const s3 = new aws.S3({
        accessKeyId: process.env.AKY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SAKY,
        region: process.env.ARION
      });
  
      const params = {
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: 'task-file-previews/' + taskId + '/' + uuid.v4() + '.png',
        Body: buffer,
      };
  
      const response = await s3.upload(params).promise().catch(err=>{console.log(err)})

      // Use the Location property directly
      const pdfURL = response.Location;
  
      return pdfURL;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("AWS :"+ error.message);
      return null
    }
  }
```

console.log(data);
prints some passthrough error. like below:

```
PassThrough {
  _events: {
    close: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onclose] },
    error: [Function: onerror],
    prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
    finish: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onfinish] },
    drain: undefined,
    data: undefined,
    end: undefined,
    readable: undefined,
    unpipe: [Function: onunpipe]
  },
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: [],
    bufferIndex: 0,
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    [Symbol(kState)]: 1048844
  },
  _writableState: WritableState {
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    length: 0,
    corked: 0,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writelen: 0,
    bufferedIndex: 0,
    pendingcb: 0,
    [Symbol(kState)]: 17580812,
    [Symbol(kBufferedValue)]: null
  },
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _eventsCount: 5,
  [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
}
```

i am trying to generate pdf thumbnail from pdf Url but it shows some passthrough error iam using **pdf-thumbnail** npm package. i am using this package but it is not working. if i use generate it shows pdfThumbnail.generate is not a function. i want to upload the thumbnail to S3 how will i upload this response ?

Comment: i want to upload the thumbnail to S3 how will i upload this response ?